# Condition for uniqueness of inscribed star pentagons given ordered side lengths

Tags: euclidean-geometry, maxima-minima

[This paper](http://ftp.jssac.org/Editor/Suushiki/V18/No1/V18N1_102.pdf) describes computations of the circumradius of cyclic polygons given by the lengths
of the sides. For cyclic pentagons, the defining polynomial of $r^2$ has degree $7$, so there are at most $7$ pentagons of given side lengths.

The convex inscribed polygon of given side lengths (if exists) is unique (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280279/)).

My question is about star pentagons, there are at least three cases:

1. Given side lengths $(2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3)$ there are $7$ pentagons, $2$ of them are star pentagons.

| r=2.38343 | r=1.69187 | r=1.66074 | r=1.62688 | r=1.58755 | r=1.52302 | r= 1.50091 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

In the figure the order of vertices on the circle for the convex pentagon is ABCDEF, for the star pentagons is ADBEC. ([code](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rnDxcZxVVK/))

2. Changing $e=3$ to $3.1$, for $(2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3.1)$ there exist only $5$ pentagons, no star pentagons.
3. Between $3$ and $3.1$ there is a value $e\approx3.0065$ such that the star pentagon of given side lengths is unique.

I want to prove:

> Given side lengths $(a,b,c,d,e)$, $e$ largest, and there is a star pentagon. If the pentagon formed by tangents at $A,B,C,D,E$ has signed area zero, then it is unique star pentagon.
> [In the below picture, let the self-intersection point be $P$, then the signed area of $T_{AB}T_{BC}T_{CD}T_{DE}T_{EA}$ is $\text{area}(PT_{BC}T_{CD})-\text{area}(PT_{AB}T_{EA}T_{DE})$.]

[image]

My partial solution:
For star pentagons inscribed in a circle of radius $r$,
$$\tag1\label1\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{2r}\right)+\arcsin\left(\frac{b}{2r}\right)+\arcsin\left(\frac{c}{2r}\right)+\arcsin\left(\frac{d}{2r}\right)-\arcsin\left(\frac{e}{2r}\right)=\pi$$
If the pentagon $T_{AB}T_{BC}T_{CD}T_{DE}T_{EA}$ has signed area zero, then (in unsigned area):
$$\text{area}(OT_{AB}T_{BC})+\text{area}(OT_{BC}T_{CD})+\text{area}(OT_{CD}T_{DE})\\-\text{area}(OT_{DE}T_{EA})-\text{area}(OT_{EA}T_{AB})=0$$
so
$$\frac12r|T_{AB}T_{BC}|+\frac12r|T_{BC}T_{CD}|+\frac12r|T_{CD}T_{DE}|-\frac12r|T_{DE}T_{EA}|-\frac12r|T_{EA}T_{AB}|=0$$
Dividing by $\frac12r$ and rewriting distances,
$$|T_{AB}B|+|BT_{BC}|+|T_{BC}C|+|CT_{CD}|+|T_{CD}D|+|DT_{DE}|\\-|T_{DE}E|+|ET_{EA}|-|T_{EA}A|+|AT_{AB}|=0$$
Since $|T_{AB}B|=|AT_{AB}|=r\tan\frac{\angle AOB}2,\ldots$ we get
$$\tan\frac{\angle AOB}2+\tan\frac{\angle BOC}2+\tan\frac{\angle COD}2+\tan\frac{\angle DOE}2-\tan\frac{\angle EOA}2=0$$
Since $\frac{d}{dr}\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{2r}\right)=-\frac{\frac a2}{r \sqrt{r^2-(\frac a2)^2}}=-\frac1r\tan\frac{\angle AOB}2$, the LHS of \eqref{1} has a stationary point at the solution $r$. From this can we conclude the star pentagons of given side lengths is unique?

Also, in \eqref{1} the last term has negative sign where I assumed the arc $\overparen{ADE}$ is smaller than half a circle. For $(2.7, 2.75, 2.8, 2.9, 3)$, and \eqref{1} has unique solution but there are $2$ star pentagons (for one of them $\overparen{ADE}$ is larger than half a circle). How can I exclude this?

---

Some plots: ($r$ increases from its minimum $e/2$.)
(Let $A'$ be a point on the circle such that $EA'=e$. If $A'=A$ we get a solution.)

For $(a,b,c,d,e)=(2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3)$
[image]([code](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VCF5z2QvGz/))
$A'$ passes through $A$, reverses direction, and passes through $A$, so there are $2$ solutions.

For $(a,b,c,d,e)=(2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3.0065)$
[image]([code](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/MY55Gdq2PX/))
when $A'$ reaches $A$ it reverses direction, so there is a unique solution.

Comment: "the convex pentagon of given side lengths (if exists) is unique." This seems highly unlikely. Is there a missing hypothesis?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry I forgot to write "cyclic"